# Did not understand "MustUnderstand" header(s)

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am working with a vendor's SOAP API. I followed [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client) but I am getting a strange error when trying to execute a client command. I'm pretty new to SOAP but from what I can tell it sounds like something with authentication is not right. At the moment, my code is:

```
    private bool EmailExists(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
            myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

            myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

            EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("https://api.subscribermail.com/ws/latest/smrecipient?wsdl");

            var smrecipientClient = new smrecipient.smrecipientPortTypeClient(myBinding, ea);
            smrecipientClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "[obfuscated]";
            smrecipientClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "[obfuscated]";

            smrecipientClient.Open();

            var data = smrecipientClient.queryRecipientByEmail(email);

            smrecipientClient.Close();

            if (data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.id)) return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

When I step over `var data = smrecipientClient.queryRecipientByEmail(email);`, I see the following error in the catch block:

`{"Did not understand \"MustUnderstand\" header(s):{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action, {http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}To"}`

There is no inner exception but the stack trace is:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at [myApp].Web.SMRecipient.smrecipientPortType.queryRecipientByEmail(String emailAddress)
   at [myApp].Web.SMRecipient.smrecipientPortTypeClient.queryRecipientByEmail(String emailAddress) in C:\Dev\[myApp]\my-website\Web\Connected Services\SMRecipient\Reference.cs:line 1555
   at [myApp].Web.Controllers.SubscriptionsController.EmailExists(String email) in C:\Dev\[myApp]\my-website\Web\Controllers\SubscriptionsController.cs:line 128
```

I did see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353412/did-not-understand-mustunderstand-headers-error-in-soapui-response) but do not understand the solution (how would I set the WSS Password Type through code in my example). Additionally, one of my colleagues said I need to do authentication completely differently and update the Reference.cs of the web service so that the main class inherits from `Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol`, but the problem is, the web service's Reference.cs does not have a main class.

Comment: Can you use basicHttpBinding?:

basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="https">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <message clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I will try this now and let you know!

Comment: @FaizanRabbani That worked! I am getting a RecordNotFoundException from the vendor's API which was the desired result. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to see it worked, I have posted the comment as my answer, let me know if you require any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WsHttpBinding` is used for more advanced WS related reliable messaging. In your scenrio simple `BasicHttpBinding` could work fine as well.

Can you use basicHttpBinding?:

```
    <basicHttpBinding> 
     <binding name="https"> 
      <security mode="Transport"> 
       <message clientCredentialType="Basic"/> 
      </security>
     </binding> 
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Yep. I just had to update the first two lines of code inside the `try` of the `EmailExists` function:

`BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();`
`myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;`